# Can't connect to serial port

Tags: serial, led

I'm trying to make my Arduino's LED blink for the first time, but when I try to upload the code I get the following error in the Serial Monitor:

> Error opening serial port '/dev/ttyACM0'.
>   Try consulting the documentation at http://playground.arduino.cc/Linux/All#Permission

BTW, I have `serial.debug_rate=9600`, so I don't think that's the problem. Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Did you consider following the provided link and trying the things it suggests?

Comment: You can also find more information and tips here: https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/08/24/diagnosing-arduino-problems-in-linux/

Answer (score 3):

It seems your serial does not have the right permissions to be opened in *user mode*. Try adjusting that by typing

```
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0
```

on the console (open it by <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>).

Answer (score 1):

That issue is due to your username not being in the dialout group.
Try: `sudo usermod -a -G dialout yourusername` and rebooting to load the changes, then check again if the problem still persists...

I wrote an article about that here: [Solving Arduino IDE upload problem, and serial monitor error on Ubuntu](http://osrc.rip/Articles/SolvingArduinoUploadProblemOnLinux.html).